# jQuery .validate: get number of invalids onfocusout

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

onsubmit I'm displaying the number of errors in my form at the top of the form.

What I would like to do is update that number after a user fixes an error and focus's out of a field. It seemed like using onfocusout: was the way to go.

I'm trying to use validator.numberOfInvalids() inside my onfocusout: function but seems that it only works onsubmit.

Is there a way to recount the number of errors without resubmitting the form?

EDIT: well after I posted I got an idea, which works. All but for the last error fix. The error message still says 1. Getting number of errors would be a great way to do this.

EDIT: there are a number of $.validator.addMethod()'s used and a number of functions that support those. The whole thing is written using Box T3. I hope this helps.

```
    function billing_form_setup(billingForm) {

    validator = $(billingForm).validate({
        debug: true,
        meta: "validate",
        ignore: [],
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            // this sets the error placement for jquery UI select menu's
            if (element.is("select")) {
                $(element)
                .closest( "div" )
                .find( ".ui-selectmenu-button" )
                .css('border', '2px solid #d11515')
                .css('box-shadow', ' 0px 0px 16px -8px rgba(209,21,21,1)');
            }
            else { // default error placement
                $( element )
                .closest( "form" )
                .find( "span[class='" + element.attr( "id" ) + "']" )
                .append( error );
            }
        },
        rules: {
            p_card_number: {
                required: true,
                creditCheck: true,
                minlength: 12
            },
            p_exp_date: {
                required: true,
                dateCheck: true,
                checkDateExpired: true
            },
            p_card_code: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                digits: true
            }   
        },
        errorElement: "p",
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            // set up for showing one error message above form
            errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                message = errors == 1
                ? 'There is a problem 1 field'
                : 'There is a problem with ' + errors + ' fields.';
                $(".pmnt-type-form div.error span").html(message);
                $(".pmnt-type-form div.error").show();
            } else {
                $(".pmnt-type-form div.error").hide();
            }
        },
        onfocusout: function(element, event) { 
            // don't do this! ;-)
           //$("#billing-form").submit();
        }

    });
};
```

EDIT: new showErrors code:

```
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var fields = (errors === 1) ? ' field' : ' fields';
                message = 'There is a problem with ' + errors + fields;
                $(".pmnt-type-form div.error span").html(message);
                $(".pmnt-type-form div.error").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".pmnt-type-form div.error").hide();
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
```

@Sparky: thanks for your help!

Comment: Code, Please..?

Comment: Yes there is but before that show us what have you done till now. ;) so that we can be sure you are human and not a robot...  :) :) haha

Comment: Show the rest of the relevant code!

Comment: The rest of the code is quite extensive, really - this is the relevant code. IMO more code would just muck up the question. In the onfocusout I'd like to get the count of invalids. The rest of the code works fine, I just wanted to add this functionality.

Comment: You should at least show enough code to demonstrate the issue. Minimal HTML markup and enough of the code from `.validate()` to make it do something.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   ~ After all, do not expect anyone else to fill in your blanks just to construct a demo of a possible solution.

Comment: Your question is about how `.numberOfInvalids()` is working and didn't think that was important part to show?  Move your `invalidHandler` code over to the `showErrors` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> onsubmit I'm displaying the number of errors in my form at the top of the form.

This should be done using the `showErrors` function.  And we have no idea if this is what you're doing because you've shown us very little.

The `onfocusout` callback is the function that merely triggers validation when the user leaves an input... it was never meant for triggering other things.

You should also **never** be putting a jQuery `.submit()` inside of any of the jQuery Validate plugin's callback handler functions.

Why?  Because the plugin is already automatically capturing the click, blocking the submit, checking for validation errors, showing/hiding messages, and then allowing the submit only if/when valid.  You are breaking this whole process by inserting a `.submit()`.

The `.numberOfInvalids()` method is most commonly used inside of [the `showErrors` callback](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors).

> What I would like to do is update that number after a user fixes an error and focus's out of a field.

It's working for me when I put `.numberOfInvalids()` where it belongs:  [jsfiddle.net/yLjrL8ay/](http://jsfiddle.net/yLjrL8ay/)

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $("#summary").html("Your form contains " + this.numberOfInvalids() + " errors");
}
```

**EDIT**:

Currently, you have the relevant code within the `invalidHandler`.  However, the `invalidHandler` only fires when the form is invalid... therefore, if you fix all errors, the `invalidHandler` is not going to fire again.

As stated in the original answer, use `showErrors` instead.

**EDIT 2**:

There was also a problem with your logic here...

```
if (errors) {
    // construct message
    ....
```

When `errors` goes to `0`, the condition will be false, and your message could never update.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. The validation works fine, but now the highlighting of the invalid fields is not showing. Does something need to be reset. See added code above

Comment: @dstefani, simply put `this.defaultShowErrors();` as the last line of the `showErrors` function.  This restores the default functionality that you're already using with `errorPlacement`, etc.

Comment: @dstefani, see my Edit #2 in regards to the last edit on your OP... when you have zero errors, your message will not update.